# Display on WP Bakery /Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I'm very happy to be part of this group (Sorry for my english I'm french...).
Here's my question : I would like to create a section like the one below by touching the css as little as possible. How do I manage my columns?
Thanks a lot for your feedback[Here is my wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh6Ah.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your wish is very easy with WP Bakery? Create a row with 3 columns and add needed components like text and single image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Simply Take three section by creating new section wpbakery builder ,
Then you divide h2 & paragraph in 1st & last column , while You can add image on centered Column.

Comment: it's so simple that I don't even know why I didn't think of it :-) Thanls a lot